# Content Query part & blog PostCategory issue with single category

Tags: content-query-web-part, blog

I'm using the content query webpart to query a blog list and it is working well for the most part, the issue i'm having has to do with the categories that the blog has been associated with when a blog has more than one category the PostCategory field contains data that looks like this:

```
1;#Category1;#2;#Category2
```

Which contains both the id and the name of the category which I can use to build a link to the blog category filter page. When a given blog entry is associated with one category it the PostCategory field just renders out like this:

```
Category1
```

My question is how can I get the id of the category where there is only one? I know this has to be possible because SharePoint gets it with the stock blog template. I have combed through the blog.xsl file and have come up empty, any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the Category field in the CommonViewFields property of the web part to pass as "Lookup" type? (a la: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497457.aspx)

Edit: snippet from my .webpart file as per the comments:

```
 <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">PostCategory</property>
```

Comment: Yes I did. I'm getting 1;#Category1;#2;#Category2 when the blog entry has more than one associated category so it's pulling the right data. The problem is when there is only one there is no ID in the string.

Comment: Odd - I've not seen this... and you're doing just a bog standard xsl:value-of yeah?

Comment: Do you see an id in the string when there is just a single category association?

Comment: Yep - though for me I had a teamsite at top of site collection level, created a blog underneath it, fired up the Publishing Infrastructure to get me the CQWP, added it, modded ItemStyle to spit out @PostCategory, exported a CQWP, wired it up to Posts list, added PostCategory to CommonViewFields, and it renders the number of the category as well as the name, even when only 1 is selected.

Comment: Tried same thing you did, fresh team site with a fresh blog and the same result as before, could you update your post with what you have in your working exported webpart for => DataMappings, DataMappingViewFields, CommonViewFields?

Comment: Added - though my .webpart file doesn't have DataMappings or DataMappingViewFields... (just realised, this is in my 2007 VM, and you're asking about 2010...) - try clearing those properties?

Comment: I Tried your suggestion and unfortunately i'm left with same result.